# How would I temporarily store a column as a json object to derive other columns?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataset with key value pairs like this

```
likes=dogs;hates=birds;likes=sports;eats=cheese
```

I then turn it into json

```
{"likes": ["dogs","sports"], "hates": ["birds"], "eats": ["cheese"]}
```

Is there a way I can keep this json datastructure without casting it to a string, so I can derive more columns from it on a row by row basis? I would like it to look something like this, without having to turn decode the json from string every column added.

```
        Dataset<Row> df1 = df.withColumn("interests", callUDF("to_json", col("interests")))
                         .withColumn("likes", callUDF("extract_from_json", "likes", col("interests")))
                         .withColumn("hates", callUDF("extract_from_json", "hates", col("interests")))
                         .withColumn("hates", callUDF("extract_from_json", "eats", col("interests")));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working off the original file

```
likes=dogs;hates=birds;likes=sports;eats=cheese
```

then you could read it in with sc.textFile then do some simple RDD manipulations.

```
val df = sc.textFile(file)
  .flatMap(x => x.split(";"))
  .map(x => (x.split("=")(0), x.split("=")(1)))
  .toDF("interest","value")

df.withColumn("tmp",lit(1)).groupBy("tmp").pivot("interest").agg(collect_list("value"))

+---+--------+-------+--------------+
|tmp|    eats|  hates|         likes|
+---+--------+-------+--------------+
|  1|[cheese]|[birds]|[dogs, sports]|
+---+--------+-------+--------------+
```